# How can I calculate the density of a gas mixture using the ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, ideal-gas

I am trying to calculate the density of the ideal gas mixture given the following data:

> The gases are helium and oxygen. There are $\pu{8 g}$ $\ce{He}$ and $\pu{16 g}$ $\ce{O2}$. The temperature is $\ce{300 K}$. The pressure is $\pu{100 kN m-2}$.

So I know density is mass per volume, but I don't know where to get the volume from. I thought I would get it from the Ideal Gas law, but I can find $p\cdot V$ for both gases after finding the quantity for both gases, but I don't know where to go from there. I only know that the pressures add up to  $\pu{100 kN m-2}$.

Comment: The volume is the same for both gases, and the sum of their partial pressures is equal to 100 kPa.  Do it algebraically, and solve for V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample is made of $2$ moles $\ce{He}$ + $0.5$ mol $\ce{O2}$. So the total gas amount is $n = 2.5$ moles. Its total mass is $m = \pu{ 2 mol · 4 g/mol + 0.5 mol · 32 g/mol = 24 g}$  Now the volume of $2.5$ mole ideal gas can be calculated from : $V = nRT/p$, with $p = 10^5$ Pa, and $T = 300$ K. Divide $24 $ g by this volume, and you get the answer. Go ! Do the calculation yourself !